# can I detect the status of a scheduled task like I do with services using serviceController?

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks

I am building a status page for my web app and want to have it show me the status of critical home grown windows services and scheduled tasks.

I have finished setting up the logic to monitor and report on the status of windows services using serviceController.

how do i do the same with mt scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, as you can with ServiceController.  There is a [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383608%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but no managed API for this.  You'd need to use the COM API directly.